# Wide image on Bootstrap container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I would like a wide image on Bootstrap container.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
        <img data-layout="wide" src="big-image.jpg" alt="Big image" class="embedded_image">
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the image to come out of the container to be extended from right to left. I do not have the means to add an extra class to the source image, but I can only add CSS via `.embedded_image[data-layout="wide"]`

I tried this CSS code:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 50vw);
margin-right: calc(50% - 50vw);
max-width: 1000%;
width: auto;
```

Comment: remove the second `.container`. You shouldn't nest Bootstrap containers. `.container-fluid` will go full width.

Comment: No I won't remove the second container... I need this to structure the text post.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Nesting Bootstrap containers is bad practice, and most likely unnecessary to achieve your desired page layout.

However, here's a solution assuming you want to keep the containers as is. To center the image in `container`, you can wrap it in a parent `div` and apply [`justify-content: center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content) to the parent. You can then set the maximum width of the image to make sure it doesn't get wider than `container-fluid`. [`object-fit: contain`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) will make sure that the aspect ratio is preserved.

Note that I've added colored outlines to the `container` and `container-fluid` for illustration purposes.

```css
.container-fluid {
  outline: solid blue 2px;
}

.container {
  outline: solid red 2px;
}

.image-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.embedded_image[data-layout="wide"] {
  object-fit: contain;
  max-width: 97vw;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-container">
        <img data-layout="wide" src="https://place-hold.it/700x100/666" alt="Big image" class="embedded_image">
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img data-layout="wide" src="https://place-hold.it/300x100/666" alt="Big image" class="embedded_image">
      </div>
      <br/>
      <div class="image-container">
        <img data-layout="wide" src="https://place-hold.it/900x100/666" alt="Big image" class="embedded_image">
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot adding somes div with class. I can only modify CSS of embedded_image img class.